# Leap Year Local Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I was to set a `NSLocalNotification` with a fire date of 29th Feb 2016 (which is a leap year) and to have a yearly repeat of the notification would it only fire every leap year or does it also fire on non leap years (1st March)?

Comment: I don't know, but why not actually test it? You can change the date and time in either your actual testing device or the simulator... Good luck!

Comment: And please post the answer here when you find it! It would be interesting to find out (although I'm pretty sure it should only fire on leap years)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing it on the device I found that it does fire every year but fires on the 28th Feb on non leap years.

Intrestingly on leap years (apart from the initial one, 2016 in this case) it fires on both the 28th and 29th.

Comment: Please file a radar on that, just so that Apple are aware of the multiple firings and log the issue in [openradar.org](http://openradar.appspot.com/page/1) so others can track it